# Trigger FCKeditor's fix syntax code

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I noticed that fckeditor tries to fix bad html syntax. I was wondering if there was a way to trigger that outside of the editor through the PHP API? I have 100+ old article posts which need quite a bit of syntax fixing and don't want to have to load each individually into the editor and save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's any help to oyu, but you might be interested in not only using FCKEditors API, but the built-in functionality: http://devzone.zend.com/241/tidying-up-your-html-with-php-5/

Also quite good: http://htmlpurifier.org/